# Spring-ws how to add an attribute to soap action in request body

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm using Spring-WS to consume a following wsdl:
https://pz.gov.pl/pz-services/SignatureVerification?wsdl
I've generated java classes to do this just like in this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Documentation of this wsdl file specifies, that a request has to have an attributes callId, and requestTimestamp set just like in the following example:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tpus="http://verification.zp.epuap.gov.pl">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <tpus:verifySignature callId="6347177294896046332" requestTimestamp="2014-06-30T12:01:30.048+02:00">
         <tpus:doc>PD94bWwgdmVyc2E+</tpus:doc>
             <tpus:attachments>
                 <tpus:Attachment>
                    <tpus:content>PD94bWwgdmVyc2+</tpus:content>
                      <tpus:name>podpis.xml</tpus:name>
                 </tpus:Attachment>
             </tpus:attachments>
     </tpus:verifySignature>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>`

My request looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-82BA5532C">
            <ns3:verifySignature
                xmlns:ns3="http://verification.zp.epuap.gov.pl"
                xmlns="">
                <doc>PD94bWwgdmVyc2E+</doc>
                <attachments>
                    <Attachment>
                        <content>PD94bWwgdmVyc2+</content>
                        <name>podpis.xml</name>
                    </Attachment>
                </attachments>
            </ns3:verifySignature>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So as you can see i lack the callId and requestTimestamp attributes. How i can add them if my code to send the request looks like this?

```
public class TrustedProfileValidator extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
private static final Logger tpLogger = Logger.getLogger(TrustedProfileValidator.class);

/**
 * Trusted profile validator constructor
 */
public TrustedProfileValidator() {
    tpLogger.info("Trusted profile validator service.");
}

public VerifySignatureResponse validate(byte[] documentInByte64, ArrayOfAttachment arrayOfAttachments) {
    tpLogger.info("Checking trusted profile validation");
    VerifySignature request = new VerifySignature();
    request.setDoc(documentInByte64);
    request.setAttachments(arrayOfAttachments);

    return (VerifySignatureResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
            "https://int.pz.gov.pl/pz-services/SignatureVerification", request,
            new SoapActionCallback("verifySignature"));
}
```

}

Comment: Well I guess there is something wrong. In the WSDL you gave I see no information about reqGetTpUserObjectsInfo, callId and requestTimestamp; so or yuo are read another documentation o you posted a different WSDL

Comment: because the example (which is in the documentation) is for another method, callId and a requestTimestamp are a parameters which has to be set for every request. So my request should also have these parameters. I'll edit the example, so there is no misunderstanding anymore

Comment: what it's strange is that in the WSDL definition there is no reference to the attributes callId and requestTimestamp and to the object reqGetTpUserObjectsInfo; so it seems to me that or there is some error (maybe another WSDL) or in the documentation there is something related to the security (e.g. ws-security); in the case of ws-security there are some parameters like the ones you wrote but they are written in soap header; you can obtain the same identical result of spring-ws also by testing the WS by using SOAP-UI

Comment: i used ws-security to sign the message, but it's specified that the Soap action has to have these parameters. Is there a way to edit a soap message before it's sent? Like an interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems little bit strange because the sample you provided doesn't reagard the soap-action; but as i can see in the sample there are some parameters added to the soap body and these parameters are not mapped in the WS schema

In any case if the documentation says that the soap action string must have these parameters you can still use what you used but you must pass the attributes to the SoapActionCallback:
For example you can do the following

```
wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("wsUri", youRequestObj, new SoapActionCallback("verifySignature callId=\""+callId+"\"  requestTimestamp=\""+requestTimestamp+"\""));
```

In this way spring ws will write the soap action by adding the 2 attributes

But I assume that it's the soap-body content to be modified; so in this case you can use:

- org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate
- sendSourceAndReceive method of the WebServiceTemplate
- your custom SourceExtractor

For example you can use a XML template like this (done by using velocity) and called "requestTemplate.vm"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <tpus:verifySignature callId="${callId}" requestTimestamp="${timeStamp}" xmlns:tpus="http://verification.zp.epuap.gov.pl">
         <tpus:doc>${doc}</tpus:doc>
             <tpus:attachments>
                 <tpus:Attachment>
                    <tpus:content>${docContent}</tpus:content>
                      <tpus:name>${docName}</tpus:name>
                 </tpus:Attachment>
             </tpus:attachments>
     </tpus:verifySignature>
```

then in your code you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(5);
params.put("callId", "myCallId");
params.put("timeStamp", "thetimeStamp");
params.put("doc", "theDoc");
params.put("docName", "theDocName");
params.put("docContent", "theDocContent");
String xmlRequest = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "requestTemplate.vm", "UTF-8", params).replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
StreamSource requestMessage = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlRequest));
wsTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive("wsUrl", requestMessage,new new SoapActionCallback("verifySignature"),new CustomSourceExtractor());
```

where CustomSourceExtractor is where you can read the SOAP response

I did something like this

```
public class VieSourceExtractor implements SourceExtractor<YourObj>
{
@Override
public List<YourObj> extractData(Source src) throws IOException, TransformerException
{
XMLStreamReader reader = null;
try
{
reader = StaxUtils.getXMLStreamReader(src);
//read the xml and create your obj
return yourResult;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
throw new TransformerException(e);
}
finally
{
if (reader != null)
{
try
{
reader.close();
}
catch (XMLStreamException e)
{
logger.error("Error " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
}
}
}
}
```

I hope this can help you

Angelo

Comment: Unfortunatelly, writing `"verifySignature callId=\""+callId+"\"  requestTimestamp=\""+requestTimestamp+"\""` to SoapActionCallback returned with: `The given SOAPAction verifySignature callId="6347177294896046332" requestTimestamp="2016-11-14T10:14:24.524+01:00 does not match an operation`. And i checked the sent request, xml was not modified. So it's not possible to modify soap action like that. I'll try your other tips :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's the XML Body to be changed like i told you... let me know... now i'm curious; by the way... the VM template i wrote must be improved... it is only a sample

Comment: I ended up modifying java spring generated classes and it turned out that these parameters are in the documentation, but the documentation is outdated... Thank you for your help